# LINQ query to get all products with in Min & Max price range?

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I want to fetch all products in the range of min & max price. Actually I am passing a product(object) with price range in it, and by taking its Min & Max price value I want to fetch all products from database in that range.
I have try something like:

```
public List<Products> SuggestedProducts(Product product)
{
    List<Product> products = (from c in db.Products.Include(x = > x.Category).Include(x = > x.User.CityId.Country).Include("Images")
                              where (c.MinPrice >= product.MinPrice) && (c.MinPrice <= product.MaxPrice)
                              where (c.MaxPrice <= product.MaxPrice) && (c.MaxPrice > product.MinPrice)
                              where (c.User.CityId.Id == product.User.CityId.Id)
                              where (c.User.Id != product.User.Id)
                              select c).ToList();

    return products;
}
```

In above code, I am getting (or trying to get) all those products that fall between range of product I am passing.
**Which is not working properly. I need query to fetch my desired Product**

Note: I used `c.User.CityId.Id == product.user.CityId.Id` to fetch products of same location & `c.User.Id != product.user.Id` to skip products from same user.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @RomanKoliada : Previous edit remove that line. My provided query is not working. i need a query to fetch all products that fall in range. (As described above)

Comment: Your query looks fine. Try to double check that you do have products in your table which satisfy all of your conditions(userId, cityId and price ranges). Also it might be useful to take a look at generated sql and run it manually in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: why are you using so many `where` so many times?

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul these are conditions to get products lie within these conditions.

Comment: @ArslanAmeer you can add all these conditions in just one `where` with && operator. Look at my answer below

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul: yes. i have writen it for easy readability and understanding for a client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Product> products = db.Products.Where(c => c.MinPrice >= product.MinPrice && c.MaxPrice <= product.MaxPrice && c.User.CityId.Id == product.User.CityId.Id && c.User.Id != product.User.Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the single `where` condition for price

```
where (c.MinPrice >= product.MinPrice && c.MaxPrice <= product.MaxPrice)
```

Comment: Are you having two price field in database?

Comment: Yes. As written in code, I have two fields, min price & Max price